# Lyapunov stability - finding inequality of V_dot eq

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I'm trying to understand how the following inequality is derived.

$|x_1-2x_2| \leq \sqrt{5} ||x||$

You are only given $|x_1-2x_2|$ and told to create an inequality  that relates this to $||x||^n$

This is for a problem in which you have derived $\dot{V}(x)$ of a Lyapunov function $V(x)$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and need to create some in equality

$\dot{V} \leq f(||x||^n)$

in order to find an estimated domain of attraction for a given system

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = (x_1, x_2)^T$ and $a = (1, -2)^T$, hence
$$|x_1 - 2x_2| = |\langle a, x\rangle| \leq ||a||\cdot||x|| = \sqrt{5}||x||$$